# jquery not working on phones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website menu using a small bit of jQuery to load a specific part of an HTML page into the current page, with an ID of 'guts'. I wanted the menu to remain the same during the visit, while the 'guts' is all that changes. The URLs are also changed with the function.

I have it working properly on most desktop browsers but not on mobile devices. The content fades in and out, so the script is partially executed, but the correct content isn't brought in, and the URL remains the same.

I'm very new, and thinking it's some sort of syntax error. Any help is very appreciated. Thank you.

[**Working Page**](http://www.alkusaristone.com/index_final.html):

**My Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var newHash      = "",
        $mainContent = $("#content-wrap"),
        $el;



    $("#menu a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var _link = this.href;
        $mainContent
                .fadeOut(1000, function() {
                    $mainContent.hide().load(_link + " #guts", function() {
                        $mainContent.fadeIn(1000);
                        window.history.pushState(null, null, _link);
                        $(window).trigger("pathchange");
                        });
                    });
        return false;

    });

});
```

Comment: ...and the HTML? Of the page, and of the page(s) being loaded via `load`? (A link to your site is not sufficient and should, in fact, be removed. External links rot, making the question useless to others in the future.)

Comment: Checked it on my phone, links worked fine for me? Was able to navigate, click through and everything. Only issue was that it isn't responsive, but upon checking it in desktop I realized that it's not meant to be. (on iphone 5s vers. 8.3 using Safari)

Answer (score 2):

I would do this in quite different way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var newHash      = "",
    $mainContent = $("#content-wrap"),
    $el;



$("#menu a").on("click tap", function(event) {

    var _link = $(this).attr('href');


    $mainContent.fadeOut(1000);

    // Sends GET request to _link + "#guts" with empty arguments({})
    // And after it does the stuff with htmlData =(response) in callback func.        
    $.get(_link + "#guts", {}, function(htmlData) {

           // Waits for fadeout function
           while($mainContent.attr('display') != 'none') {}

           // Fills the content of $mainContent div with response data
           $mainContent.html(htmlData);

           // Does your stuff           
           $mainContent.fadeIn(1000);
           window.history.pushState(null, null, _link);
           $(window).trigger("pathchange");
    } 
}
```

Hope it will works :)
Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

The website link which you have provided is not a **responsive website** for making it to display properly in all the devices.

This would be helpful for you http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp in making your website responsive.

There is no fault in your jQuery code.